# Mixing EquivalentClass and SubClass in OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, description-logic

I'm curious about mixing SubClassOf and EquivalentClass in a Class description, and how a reasoner would behave.

Specifically, if I have both an EquivalentClass and a SubClassOf assertion for the same Class, do both the EquivalentClass AND the SubClassOf conditions need to be satisfied for an individual to be classified in that Class, or only the EquivalentClass?

Or is this a bad practice?

For example (Declarations omitted):

```
ObjectPropertyRange(:format :Bar)
ObjectPropertyRange(:format owl:Thing)
EquivalentClass(:Foo ObjectSomeValuesFrom(:format :Bar))
SubClassOf(:Foo :Sna)
```

I want to ensure that in the case below, `:x` is classified as `:Foo`, because both the EquivalentClass and SubClassOf assertions are satisfied:

```
ClassAssertion(:x :Sna)
ObjectPropertyAssertion(:format :x :someBar)
```

But `:y` is not, because the SubClassOf is not satisfied:

```
ClassAssertion(:y :NotASna)
ObjectPropertyAssertion(:format :y :someOtherBar)
```

Thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question but I'll try to clarify some things. First of all, the following axioms seem irrelevant for your question (and the second is redundant anyway because `owl:Thing` is any property's range):

```
ObjectPropertyRange(:format :Bar)
ObjectPropertyRange(:format owl:Thing)
```

The other thing is that the `EquivalentClasses`-axioms can be seen as a syntactic sugar for `SubClassOf`-axioms, e.g.

```
EquivalentClasses(C1 C2)
```

is logically equivalent to

```
SubClassOf(C1 C2)
SubClassOf(C2 C1)
```

So you can rewrite your `EquivalentClasses` as:

```
SubClassOf(ObjectSomeValuesFrom(:format :Bar) :Foo)
SubClassOf(:Foo ObjectSomeValuesFrom(:format :Bar))
```

This would maybe simplify understanding of what entailments your ontology makes.

Now, if you say:

```
ClassAssertion(:x :Sna)
ObjectPropertyAssertion(:format :x :someBar)
```

I am assuming that you want to say:

```
ClassAssertion(:x :Sna)
ClassAssertion(:someBar :Bar)
ObjectPropertyAssertion(:format :x :someBar)
```

This entails that `:x` is both `:Foo` and `:Sna`, which is certainly possible because `:Foo` is a subclass of `:Sna`.

When you say

```
ClassAssertion(:y :NotASna)
ObjectPropertyAssertion(:format :y :someOtherBar)
```

I assume that you mean:

```
ClassAssertion(:y :NotASna)
ClassAssertion(:someOtherBar :Bar)
DisjointClasses(:NotASna :Sna)
ObjectPropertyAssertion(:format :y :someOtherBar)
```

This is a logical inconsistency because `:y` is entailed to be a `:Foo` (which is a subclass of `:Sna`), but at the same time `:y` is asserted to be in a class that is disjoint from `:Sna`.

Note also that we didn't use the knowledge that

```
SubClassOf(:Foo ObjectSomeValuesFrom(:format :Bar))
```

which followed from the `EquivalentClasses`-axiom.